# Blank entry line for non-authorized users

Tags: django

I have built custom user levels for my Django app, the user levels are:

- Enumerator
- Area Supervisor
- Verification

Each user level can send the content to the next/previous one (Enumerator to Area Supervisor, Area supervisor to Enumerator & Verification, and Verification to Area supervisor only).

The user levels are also restricted by city (Area supervisor can only see the content submitted by enumerators in 'X' city, and the same applies for all user levels).

My issues with my code as seen in the screenshot:

- Enumerator1 create Content1
- Enumerator2 create Content2

Enumerator1 can see blank line (which is the content created by Enumerator2) and the same applies on Enumerator2.

Also, Enumerator, Area Supervisor, or Verification can see those blank lines of all content when the content isn't in their permission (since when for example: enumerator submit the content to area supervisor, the enumerator will have no access to that content until submitted back)

Screenshot1: Enumerator1 created content. 
[image]

Screenshot2: How Enumerator2 see the content created by Enumerator1
[image]

Screenshot3: What happens when Enumerator2 tries to access the blank line
[image]

Screenshot4: What happens when Enumerator2 tries to delete the blank line
[image]

Screenshot5: How the content appears to Area Supervisor, Verification (or any other user level except for creator)
[image]

Please find the complete source code here: https://bitbucket.org/azoughbi/cfs/src

How can i fix this issue, by not displaying those blank lines when the users does not have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `get_queryset()` method in your ModelAdmin:

```
class contentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(contentAdmin, self).get_queryset()
        # Refine your query here, filtering out the unwanted records.
        return qs
```

Comment: @AhmadZoughbi, I'm wondering if the answer worked for you? If you've managed to find a better solution, please share it with us to make this post complete. But if this answer eventuallly helped you to resolve your problem, consider marking it as accepted, so that the others can rely on this solution.

Comment: Thanks Alex it worked finally, for reference here's the complete code

`def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(OrganizationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_Enumerator:
            return qs.filter(Q(Send='is_Enumerator') | Q(Send='send to Enumerator'))

        elif request.user.is_AreaSupervisor:
            return qs.filter(Q(Send='is_AreaSupervisor') | Q(Send='send to Area Supervisor'))

        elif request.user.is_Verification:
            return qs.filter(Q(Send='is_Verification') | Q(Send='send to Verification'))

        return qs`